# creating alias in wamp

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I have wamp site on port 81 ( i use IIS alot which is on port 80)

Currently my site is

http://localhost:81/MySite/ "C:\wamp\www\MySite"

How can i set up "MySite" profiles so that is "MySite" is the root. ie "/css/style.css" works.

When i use the wizard in wamp to create alias directory i get the following error

"Directory does not exist"

Yes, a nice descriptive error. Tho the directory is there.

Answer (score 1):

This may not apply to you depending on the version of WAMP you're using but at least WAMP 2.0 does provide a way to create an alias straight from its icon in the system tray: *left*-click the icon in the system tray; in the menu that pops up, select `Apache` | `Alias directories` | `+ Add an alias`. Any alias you create in this fashion will appear under `Apache` | `Alias directories` allowing you to view, edit or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding a virtual host

ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/MySite/"